# Can a sed address be multiline?

Tags: sed

I'm writing a sed script to remove some unused functions.

```
/private Integer functionName(/,/^  }$/ {                                                                                                                                    
d
}
```

This works fine except it leaves the blank line above the function definition:

```
private Integer functionNameAbove(...) {
...
}
// This blank line gets left behind.
private Integer functionName(...) {
...
}
```

Is there a way to set the starting address to the blank line before the function signature?

Comment: Are you open to other tools ? `sed` default is line by line and is confusing/obfuscated when you read the commands using pattern spaces etc...

Comment: Can your functions contain blank lines within them? Replace the `...`s with some truly representative text and replace the `// This blank line...` line with an actual blank line so we can hep you. It's extremely unlikely that a sed script would be the best approach to this btw, you may want to tag your question with awk.

Comment: If your goal is to end up with a file without double blank lines, then just pipe to `cat -s`. Downside is, this will not work for in-place editing.

Answer (score 0):

With Perl:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/private Integer functionName\(.*?\}//s' file
private Integer functionNameAbove(...) {
...
}
// This blank line gets left behind.
```

To edit *in place*, add `-i` switch:

```
perl -i -077 -pe ...........
```

---

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '{sub(/private Integer functionName\(.*}/, "");print}' file
private Integer functionNameAbove(...) {
...
}
// This blank line gets left behind.
```

To edit in place, add `-i inplace` switch (GNU awk):

```
awk -i inplace ..........
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/\nprivate Integer functionName(/{:a;$!{N;/\n$/!ba};d};P;D' file
```

Open a two line window throughout the length of the file and if the first line is empty and second begins `private Integer functionName(`, gather up lines until an empty line or the end of the file and delete them.

Otherwise, print then delete the first line and repeat.